# Confidence Interval around a predictor

Tags: confidence-interval, generalized-linear-model, maximum-likelihood, calibration, delta-method

I have a logistic regression as follows: $\log \frac{p}{1-p} = \beta_0 + \beta_1x$.

I'm looking for a confidence interval around a value of $x$, which would correspond to a specific value of $p$. Obviously finding the $x$ is not a problem, as $x = (\log \frac{p}{1-p} - \beta_0)/ \beta_1$, but for a confidence interval, even if I assume that the $x_{MLE} = (\log \frac{p}{1-p} - \hat\beta_0)/ \hat \beta_1$ has, approximately, a normal distribution centered at the true value - I still need the variance of this.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, so I think we could use the $\delta$-method here:

$$x(\beta_0, \beta_1) = \frac{\log \frac{p}{1-p} - \beta_0}{\beta_1} \\
x(\hat \beta_0, \hat \beta_1) \approx x(\beta_0, \beta_1) + \nabla x(\beta_0, \beta_1)^T(\hat{\boldsymbol \beta} - {\boldsymbol  \beta}) \\ = \frac{\log \frac{p}{1-p} - \beta_0}{\beta_1} - \frac{\hat \beta_0 -\beta_0}{\beta_1} - \frac{\log \frac{p}{1-p} - \beta_0}{\beta_1^2}(\hat \beta_1 - \beta_1) \\
\mathbb V(x(\hat \beta_0, \hat \beta_1)) \approx \frac{\mathbb V(\hat \beta_0)}{\beta_1 ^2} + (\frac{\log \frac{p}{1-p} - \beta_0}{\beta_1^2})^2\mathbb V(\hat \beta_1) +2(\frac{1}{\beta_1})(\frac{\log \frac{p}{1-p} - \beta_0}{\beta_1^2})cov(\hat \beta_0, \hat \beta_1)
$$

And then maybe estimate the derivatives by their MLE's version (i.e. replacing ($\beta_0, \beta_1$) with ($\hat \beta_0, \hat \beta_1$).